# Uploading a file from an SSH server with python (alternative to PyAutoIt)

Tags: python, ssh, upload

I found a small script that can select data in the explorere to upload it using PyAutoIt. The script looks like this:

```
autoit.win_active("Open") 
sleep(2)
autoit.control_send("Open","Edit1",data_path) 
sleep(1.5)
autoit.control_send("Open","Edit1","{ENTER}")
```

I want to do the same thing, but from my Debian GNU/Linux SSH server. The problem is that PyAutoIt only works for windows. Are there any well documented alternatives out there that I could use to preform the same actions?

Answer (score 0):

You could use native python and scp

```
import subprocess
# Use subprocess to run 'scp' take FILE and pass it to the ssh host
subprocess.run(["scp", FILE, "USER@SERVER:PATH"])
#e.g. subprocess.run(["scp", "somefile.txt", "john@doe.org:/path/to/somefile.txt"])
```

Note that you have to generate an ssh key so that scp automatically gets authenticated - that way you will not be asked to provide the password.

Alternatively you could probably do (I have not tested this)

```
import subprocess
# Use subprocess to run 'scp' take FILE and pass it to the ssh host
subprocess.run(["scp", FILE, "USER:PASSWORD@SERVER:PATH"])
#e.g. subprocess.run(["scp", "somefile.txt", "john:secretpassword@<IPADDRESSorDNSNAME>:/path/to/somefile.txt"])
```